# Функция выполняется только один раз

Tags: javascript

Функция должна добавлять к тексту точки. Some text. Some text.. Some text...
Проблема заключается в том что она работает только один раз. Когда я пытаюсь вызвать ее снова, она не работает.

```
loading_chars = ['.', '..', '...'];
function funct(){

for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++){
        setTimeout(function() {
            const element = loading_chars[index];
            load_some_text.firstChild.nodeValue = "Some text" + element;
        }, 500 * index)
        }}
        
funct();
funct();
```

Comment: Почему вы так решили?

Comment: Выполняется функция и она останавливается на Some text... А должна начинаться с Some text.

Comment: Можете напихать console.log и убедиться в обратном. Первый вызов создает 3 таймера, второй вызов создает так же 3 таймера. Далее таймеры отрабатывают друг за другом. Settimeout асинхронная функция и не ждет выполнения, а идет дальше.

Answer (score 3):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что автору нужно реализовать "загрузку" используя точки (`.`, `..`, `...`, и по новой).

В таком случае подход какой-то громоздкий, зачем создавать массив из точек, когда есть метод `.repeat()`?)

```js
const Loading = (el, text, len = 3, time = 500) => {
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    if(i > len) i = 0;
    el.innerHTML = text+'.'.repeat(i++);
  }, time);
}

Loading(document.querySelector('#elem'), 'Some Text', 3, 500);
```

```html
<div id="elem"></div>
```

Ну и если действительно так, то уже давным-давно придумали реализацию на CSS.

```css
.loading::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  animation: loading 1.5s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0%, 100% {content: ''}
  25% {content: '.'}
  50% {content: '..'}
  75% {content: '...'}
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">Some text</div>
```

---

PS.

Ах, да, `setTimeout()` срабатывает **один раз** через сколько-то миллисекунд

Comment: Оу, не знал, что на CSS именно так можно анимировать, я видел какой-то другой "модный" способ.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, тоже видел, у ВК, когда тебе пишут сообщение и отображается "печатает...", но ВК удалил давно, а вспомнить не смог)

Comment: Там вроде что-то с `\A` было связано.